# repository is not updated after git pull

Tags: git, capistrano

I have made a deploy with capistrano in a repository remote.

I'm novice with git.

Now I want update some files and make updates of my website...etc with git, because capistrano its more slowly if I run new deploy.

For updates files in remote repository I have made this steps:

1º

```
git add .
```

2º

```
git commit -a -m "changes made"
```

3º

```
git push origin master
```

4º

```
git pull origin master
```

However if I see the files in remote repository the changes **have not been made** :(.

on the last step I get this result in console:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/project$ git pull origin master
user@ip.ip.ip.ip's password: 
From ip.ip.ip.ip:~/project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

### Edited with result step 3

after step 3 I get:

```
git push origin master
user@ip.ip.ip.ip's password: 
Counting objects: 110, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
Writing objects: 100% (71/71), 447.59 KiB, done.
Total 71 (delta 30), reused 0 (delta 0)
To user@ip.ip.ip.ip:~/project
   33b8849..769d87d  master -> master
```

### Edited with structure folder in remote server and capistrano deploy.rb

I have 2 directories `project` and `project.com`:

The first is **`project`** , in this directory is where the new changes are made.

and this directory have `branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs`

The second directory is **`project.com`** is my domain folder, inside this directory I have 2 directories:

**`current`**, **`releases`** and **`shared`**

Inside releases directory is my release project deployed via capistrano with a directory like:

**20120323164859**

and inside **`current`** I have my rails 3.1 app.

I want see the changes made in this directory.

**deploy.rb**

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load pathe
require "rvm/capistrano"                  # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.
require "bundler/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.2-p318@global'  
set :rvm_type, :user
set :application, "project.com"
set :user, 'user'
set :repository,  "#{user}@ip.ip.ip.ip:~/project"

set :scm, :git
set :use_sudo, false
set :keep_releases, 2
set :deploy_to, "~/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :copy


role :web, "ip.ip.ip.ip"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "ip.ip.ip.ip"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "ip.ip.ip.ip", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
load 'deploy/assets'
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Thank you!

Comment: After you have pushed your copy to origin in step 3, why would you expect there to be any differences?

Comment: @stark I have edited with result in step 3.

Comment: If you clone a new copy of your remote repo, does it show the new code?

Comment: Yeahh If I make `git clone user@ip.ip.ip.ip:~/pintureka copy` I can see the changes made :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the remote repo an actual working copy by any chance? Git wont (easily, by default) push into and update a remote working copy. You should always push to bare repos.

**Edit**

So, your actual repository is in `project`, this is a bare repository and it is where your pushes will go. Go into this directory and do `git log`, you will see your changes assuming you have your origin set correctly, etc.

To get the changes into one of the working copies in `releases`, you need to:

- deploy using proper tools, such as capistrano (which I suggest because your releases/current/shared directory structure is common of rails projects, is that what you're doing?)
- go into one of the releases directories and simply `git pull origin [branchname]`

Comment: Thank you , I have edited the post with more information for you can see what is the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @rfunduk this is the fix :D `git pull origin [branchname]` from a release version. I want do it with git because with `cap deploy` its very very slow. I dont know if there is any way for do it with capistrano more fast. Its possible do it with capistrano more fast? Thank you

Comment: capistrano is probably doing a metric ton of work that you probably do want to happen, what part exactly is slow? maybe asset pipeline compile stuff? maybe some rake task or loading the environment you're doing? this is kind of a separate question :)... glad you got it working with pull at least!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem. What do you mean by "changes have not been made"? You've just pushed your changes and therefore nothing will happen when you pull, you already have the latest code.

Comment: My problem is that I can not see the lastest code in my project. I mean, I can not see reflected the changes in the files from remote server. Thank you!